# gradle7.3.3 Could not determine java version from '11.0.10'

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying be build a java application using "`gradlew build`". I have installed gradle 7.3.3
[image]

and I have java 11.0.10.

[image]

From other answers I understand that gradle is compatible with older version but here I have java 11 and latest gradle still I am getting this error.

I also tried following  `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 7.3.3` but it is giving me following error:

[image]

Can anyone suggest what I am missing or should differently.

EDIT: (Content of gradle.wrapper.propertiese file)

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://server_path/gradle/4.6/gradle-4.6-bin.zip
```

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post console output in screen shots, just copy and paste the text formatted as code.

Comment: What is the content of your `wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`? It is also unclear where the error message in your title comes from. It is never mentioned anywhere in your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: updated with wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: So your project is designed to work with gradle 4.6 (which means it is most likely incompatible with 7.3.3). I would execute `gradlew wrapper` (instead of `gradle wrapper`) and step by step upgrade the gradle wrapper version from 4->5->6->7 and after each upgrade check for warning like "xyz is incompatible with next gradle release".

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found the resolution, posting so that it might help someone else.

***NOTE:*** *the gradle you installed on your machine and the gradle used by the project you are trying to build might be different. If you are in bad luck then they might be incompatible based on java version you have on your system.*

I had gradle 7.3.3 on my system and the project was using gradle 4.6. The gradle used by project is not compatible with java 11. So, to be on safe side I downgraded both Gradle (to v 4.6) and java (to 1.8) and it worked.

You might not required to downgrade the gradle version on your local machine. I will try that as well and update this answer.

***EDIT:*** It worked with Gradle 7.3.3, java 1.8 and the project using Gradle 4.6.